# Overflow when multiplying Integers and assigning to Long

Tags: vba, integer-overflow

If I type the following into the immediate window I get Runtime error '6': Overflow.

```
MsgBox 24 * 60 * 60
```

Why is this?

This also fails:

```
Dim giveTime  As Long 
giveTime  = 24 * 60 * 60
```

Why is this? `giveTime` is declared as a Long type, so 24 × 60 × 60 = 86400 should comfortably fit.

Comment: Further to this. - if I put msgbox 26 * 60 ^ 2 in the immediate window there's no problem. Is it an order of precedence issue? That seems unlikely...

Comment: That's because the `^` operator returns a Double, which sidesteps the problem described in my answer below.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a really odd VBA quirk. I'm amazed I've never bumped into this.

```
Dim x As Long
x = 24 * 60 * 60 ' Overflow
x = 32767 + 1 ' Overflow. 
x = 32768 + 1 ' Works fine!
```

So it looks like the `*` and `+` operators return an Integer in the first two examples. Sure enough, in the help file for the `*`operator (similar for the `+` operator):

> *result* = *number1* * *number2*
>
> [...]
>
> The data type of *result* is usually the same as that of the most precise expression.

Your literals 24, 60, and 60 are all of type Integer by default, so your `*` (or `+`) operator returns an Integer, which overflows because the result is greater than 32,767.

However, the literal 32,768 in the third example above defaults to Long type (since it is too large to be an Integer) and so the `+` returns a Long; no overflow.

The help file also says this:

> If [...] the data type of *result* is an Integer **variant** that overflows its legal range [...] Then *result* is [...] converted to a Long variant.

**Emphasis** mine. Now this little rule sounds like common sense, and anyone would reasonably assume that it applies in your case. But your numbers are of type Integer, not Variant/Integer, so VBA doesn't apply this rule! Makes absolutely no sense to me, but that's how it is, and that's what the documentation says.

Solution: make one of the arguments of your `*` operator be of a type more precise than Integer (e.g. Long) and the problem will go away.

```
x = CLng(24) * 60 * 60 ' Result is Long, works fine.
```

In fact, and this is probably why I've never bumped into this quirk, I make a habit of declaring all of my Integer variables as Long instead, unless there is a specific concern that having Longs instead of Integers will cause problems with memory use or execution time (which is almost never the case). Granted, this won't help in cases when you operate on literals smaller than 32,768, because they default to Integer type.

---

You ask in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2523246/excel-cowboy-yeeha) what a Variant/Integer is. Variant is basically a container type for any other data type. In the particular case where you make it contain an Integer:

```
Dim a As Variant ' a is now Empty
a = CInt(32767) ' a is now Variant/Integer
x = a + 1 ' works fine
```

But as noted above, a plain old Integer triggers the overflow error:

```
Dim b As Integer
b = 32767
x = b + 1 ' overflow
```

Comment: Certainly is a Quirk! So, what's the difference between a Variant/Integer and an Integer? I presume one is declared in the code, the other declared internally?

Comment: or `x = [24 * 60 * 60]`

Comment: Right. Well, `[]` square brackets are shorthand for the [`Evaluate` method](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview14.aspx?AssetId=HV080005401&lcid=2057&NS=EXCEL.DEV&Version=14&tl=2&respos=0&CTT=1&queryid=0b704676-cdcb-458a-b300-1bf8775c4ed3). So you're calling the Excel interpreter to evaluate an expression in VBA. Sounds like something that adds a lot of overhead if done repetitively, but I guess it's ok if used on occasion.

Answer (score 5):

After every number, place #. It defines each number as a double. Think of it as, each number is placed in to memory for the calculation as sort of a temp variable.
If you define each number, it will allow enough space for the calculations.

eg:

Dim x As Long

x = 24# * 60# * 60#

or 24& 'indicates long