# Error 6 with Long Variable in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

```
Sub Testing()
Dim Ttt As Long
Dim a As Variant
Dim s As String
s = "11:30:05.500"
Ttt = (11 * 50 * 10 * 10)
'a = Split(StrConv(s, 64), Chr(0))
'Ttt = TimeGet(a)
End Sub
```

I simply want to store a large number and this number is not even that large. Why is this throwing an Error Runtime Error 6?I'm sure I am doing something very stupid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315650/overflow-when-multiplying-integers-and-assigning-to-long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Ttt = (11& * 50& * 10& * 10&)
```

The reason is because the literals you're providing are being interpreted as `Integer` values, and the multiplication is happening in the order of operations, so eventually the result is too large for an `Integer` before it's assigned and implicitly cast to your `Long` data type (the `Ttt` variable).

By using the `&` type character, you're telling the compiler that your literals are actually `Long` values.