# Set Long Variable in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, long-integer, multiplication

Simple question that I can't find anywhere.  When I'm doing arithmetic, it seems the natural type is to treat value as 16Bit Integers.

I'm trying to save the result of `60 * 60 * 8 * 5` into a long, but I get an `Overflow` error  before it even has a chance to save the number as a `Long`:

```vb
Dim secondsInAWorkWeek As Long
secondsInAWorkWeek = 60 * 60 * 8 * 5
```

Long should happily store anything up to 2<sup>31</sup> = 2,147,483,647

How can I perform the multiplication safely to convert into a long

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overflow when multiplying Integers and assigning to Long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315650/overflow-when-multiplying-integers-and-assigning-to-long)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain conventions in order to force a literal to a specific type from a generic (default) type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dzy06xhf.aspx

Which leads to this code:

```
Dim secondsInAWorkWeek As Long

Let secondsInAWorkWeek = 60& * 60& * 8& * 5&
```

or:

```
Const DAYS_IN_WEEK = 5&
Const HOURS_IN_DAY = 8&
Const MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60&
Const SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60&

Dim secondsInAWorkWeek As Long

Let secondsInAWorkWeek = _
     DAYS_IN_WEEK _
   * HOURS_IN_DAY _
   * MINUTES_IN_HOUR _
   * SECONDS_IN_MINUTE
```

A lot more to write, true, but is type safe, barely needs any more explanations/comments, and it will be easy to change when they'll vote for 10 hours workdays. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, according to [Overflow when multiplying Integers and assigning to Long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17316174/1366033), you need to give Excel a running start, otherwise it will default each value in the multiplication to an integer.

Just start off by casting to long with `CLng` and it will take care of the rest:

```
Dim secondsInAWorkWeek As Long
secondsInAWorkWeek = CLng(1) * 60 * 60 * 8 * 5
```