# Rounding a variable to an integer

Tags: vba, ms-access, integer

I have a calculation like this: 3 * 12300 / 160. The result is: 230.625. But I just want the integer part, 230.

In C, this can be done using something like this: `int MyVar = (int)3*12300/160;`

Is there a way in VBA (With MS-Access) for force the result to be an integer?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vba+arrondir+nombre+entier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can round down using the [`Int` or `Fix` functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264147%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Since you know the result you want is a whole number, you should store the result in a variable of type `Long` (or `Integer` if you're absolutely certain it will always be smaller than 32768).

```
Dim l As Long
l = Int(3 / 160 * 12300) ' <~~~~ Yes, I switched the numbers around on purpose!*
MsgBox "l = " & l
```

[image]

<sub>* Why did I switch the numbers around? Because the expression `3 * 12300 / 160` will throw an error in VBA. Read here why: [Overflow when multiplying Integers and assigning to Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315650/overflow-when-multiplying-integers-and-assigning-to-long)</sub>