# VBA overflow behaviour

Tags: vba, excel, integer-overflow

I have some vba behaviour that I do not understand.
I'm running vba in a macro of excel 2016.

```
Sub alpha()

Dim a As Integer, b As Long
a = 750
b = 50 * a

Stop

End Sub
```

Running this sub results in an overflow error. Why?

Variable `a` is an integer and therefore cannot hold the number `750*50` because that is too high. But variable `b` is dimensionalised as a long - so it should be able to hold that number.

Strangely - If I change the type of variable `a` to `Long` then the code runs through.

Comment: the language does not know (yet) that the result will end up in b, all it has is the "50" so it chooses an integer to begin with.

Comment: change `Dim a As Integer` to `Dim a As Long`

Comment: Or `b = 50 * cLng(a)`:  VBA is not doing an implicit conversion from Integer to Long until *after* it has done the calculation.

Comment: And read why you can [always use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA because there is no benefit in using `Integer` at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overflow when multiplying Integers and assigning to Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315650/overflow-when-multiplying-integers-and-assigning-to-long)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum value for an `Integer` in VBA is 32,767.

You are overflowing that with `50 * a`. It's not relevant that you want to assign that to a `Long` as conceptually the multiplication happens prior to the assignment, and by then, the damage has been done.

Use a `Long` instead for `a` or write

`b = 50& * a`

to force type promotion. Either are good up to 2,147,483,647