# Why does this sub procedure return a run-time overflow error?

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to understand data types and was testing this sub procedure. The data types seem appropriate for the variables, but it doesn't work unless I change the B variable to Single or Double. This doesn't make sense to me. Why wouldn't Long work when the value being assigned to it falls within the Long data type's range? Is there some rule I am unaware of around data types?

```
Sub DataTypeChallenge ()
    Dim A As Double
    Dim B As Long
    A = 5
    B = A * 53976
    A = B * 1000000
    MsgBox A
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in what you posted `A = B *` ???

Comment: @GeekFreaky: Please add the missing parts to your code.

Comment: Fixed!!! That's what I was running.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the issue occurs in the line which might be similar to

```
A = B * 53976
```

The issue is that VBA evaluates in a first step the expression B * 53976 as long which leads to an overflow. Only in a second step VBA will cast this to double. You can fix this like that

```
A = CDbl(B) * 53976
```

Or you change the data type as you wrote in your post

**Another example**

```
Sub TestInt()

Dim myDbl As Double
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer

    a = 32000
    b = 1000
    myDbl = a + b

End Sub
```

This also generates Run Time Error 6 because the data type integer is limited to 32565 (or so) but the code sums first a + b and put the result into an integer and then converts it into a double.

Another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315650/overflow-when-multiplying-integers-and-assigning-to-long) on SO

Comment: Also, of interest, in the Immediate pane:  `?53976 * 53976` --> `Overflow` but `?53976^2` --> `2913408576`

Comment: Please see edit in my procedure. I'm not sure if I understand your explanation. Why does B have to be Double when its value is acceptable with a Long data type? I understand why A has to be Double...

Comment: Oh wait, are you saying that although A is assigned as Double, when I try to issue a value involving a Long integer, VBA ignores the fact that A is Double, and tries to store the value as if A is Long?

Comment: @GeekyFreaky The overflow occurs before the value gets assigned to `A`, while VBA thinks it is still working with `Long`

Comment: Thanks Storax but I don't get it still. Sorry! Here's my logic: A is Double - even if the expression evaluates to a Long - why wouldn't A be able to handle that when it's Double? A Double variable's range is much larger than a Long?

Comment: Thanks Ron...I'm even more confused. hahaha So VBA calculates the Long integer multiplied by the number. If there's no assignment, then what on Earth am I violating? What is causing an overflow?

Comment: Ron, I think I'm getting it...are you saying that the resulting value of that expression is treated as Long because it involves a Long integer? And since the resulting value is larger than Long, it causes an overflow error? And since it's not being assigned, then I'm assuming that there's some temporary memory space reserved for the resulting value and that's what I'm violating?

Comment: I added another example to my post.

Comment: @GeekyFreaky I think you're getting it.  I don't know about *temporary memory space* but yes, if you multiply a Long * an Integer, or Long * Long, the result must be evaluated as  Long before it gets assigned.  If either of the multiplicands are a double, the result will be evaluated as a double.  So, in addition to the answer above, you could also use `A = B * 1000000#`

Comment: Thanks so much Storax and Ron! Really appreciate your quick responses and patient guidance. Cheers!